# Check Does an element change?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to execute a command by changing the value of input `c1`. I wrote the codes as follows and I do not know why `c1` is known as `undefined`!!

Friends, can you help me how to solve this problem?

```js
var c1=parseInt(document.querySelector("#c1").value.replace(/,/g,""));

setInterval(() => {
    let c2=parseInt(document.querySelector("#c1").value.replace(/,/g,""));
    console.log(c1); // why c1 is undefined?
   
    if(c1!=c2){
     var c1=parseInt(document.querySelector("#c1").value.replace(/,/g,""));
     console.log("change");
    }
},3000)
```

```html
<input id="c1" value="12000">
```

Comment: @Mamun has suggested the correct solution. Just a little note: Try to avoid using `var` and use `let` and `const` instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are re-declaring the same variable (*c1*) again inside `setInterval()`.

**Demo:**

```js
var c1 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#c1").value.replace(/,/g,""));

setInterval(() => {
    let c2 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#c1").value.replace(/,/g,""));
    console.log(c1); // why c1 is undefined?
   
    if(c1 != c2){
     c1 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#c1").value.replace(/,/g,""));
     console.log("change");
    }
},3000);
```

```html
<input id="c1" value="12000">
```